# Setting up Blazor WebAssembly App with API with AzureAd in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, blazor, webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I'm new at Blazor and Azure Ad (or in fact authentication in generation) and I wanted to setup a simple basic application from the app generated by the Wizard in Visual Studio 2022.  I was able to get the authentication part up and running but I am not able to access the API. I am getting 401 - Unauthorized and www-authenticate in the response headers is: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Here is what I did:

1. In Visual Studio 2022, crate a new project using Blazor WebAssembly App

   - Keep Framework to .Net 6.0 (Long-term support)
   - Change Authentication type to Microsoft identity platform
   - Keep “Configured for HTTPS” on
   - Check “ASP.Net Core hosted”
   - Keep “Progressive Web Application” off
2. I confirm that I want to install “dotnet msidentity tool” by clicking the Finish button
3. In Azure “App registration” section, I choose “New registration” at the top

   - I enter “MyBlazorApp1” as the name
   - Select “Personal Microsoft accounts only” for supported type
   - Set redirect URI to SPA and `https://localhost:7095/authentication/login-callback`
   - Click Register button bottom left
   - [Screen capture of the filled fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwBc3.png)
4. [Screen capture of the created AzureAd application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMwxV.png)
5. In BlazorApp1.Client/wwwroot/appsettings.json:

   - Replace 22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222 by consumers (so that Authority is now https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers)
   - Set ClientId to the client id (1 in the above screen capture)
6. In BlazorApp1.Server/appsettings.json:

   - Set Domain to the “Primary domain” found “Azure Active Directory” Overview page.
   - Set TenantId to the tenant Id (3 in the above screen capture)
   - Set Client Id to client id (1 in the above screen capture)
7. Execute the application (Ctrl-F5)
8. Use Log In at the top right corner of the screen, everything works!
9. Go in Fetch data on the left and I get an “Unhandleded error has occurred.  Reload” at the bottom the screen.
10. On Azure, in the “Expose an API” section of the app created before, I click “Add a scope”

    - I accept the default Application ID URI made from the Client ID, click “Save and continue”
    - Set the scope name to “access_as_user”
    - Set the User constent display name to “Access as user”
    - Set the User consent description du “Access as user description”
    - Keep the state to Enabled
    - And click “Add scope”
    - [Screen capture of the fields to create the scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a6Vp.png)
11. In BlazorApp1.Client/Program.cs:

    - Changed "api://api.id.uri/access_as_user" for api://Client ID/access_as_user (4 in the above screen capture)
12. Log in, go in the Get data section on the left and I still get Unhandleded error has occurred.  Reload” at the bottom the screen. Looking in the Network section of the DevTools of Edge I can see that:

    - WeatherForecast returned a 401
    - www-authenticate in the response headers is: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
    - [DevTools screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Dyc.png)

I feel I missed something that many of you might find obvious but this is being my first Blazor with AzureAd I must admit that I am not sure exactly where to continue searching...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I've found the solution (in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp, Step 3).  It turns out that when you are using "Personal Microsoft accounts only" for the type of application, you shouldn't specify the Tenant Id in `BlazorApp1.Server/appsettings.json` but instead simply specify "custom".